# DNS Server (a newbie asking)

Tags: networking, server, dns

I'm a new ubuntu user. 
 I installed webmin to control my website better than command lines and also to not install desktop for perfomance. 
As I could understand what DNS is, how can I configure my server as a DNS server using BIND DNS server? 
 All the tutorials are just telling to use a domain for the dns server. How can I link a domain to the server without even having a DNS server? 
 And how can I set a DNS server without a domain? 
I got a registered domain but I don't know where to point it without DNS server and how to set a DNS server without a linked domain to the server? o.O 
I'm confused, please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have a Ubuntu machine being hosted for you by some company.

If so you have a web address of some sort to find that machine. Maybe its 123.456.78.90 or maybe its http://abdel.saad.hosting-company.com.
What is the address of your server, either the number or the FQDN.

A DNS server is like a phonebook it links google.com to 216.58.192.4. However domain names (at least good ones) aren't free. IF you want to buy abdelrahman.net you have to pay a registrar like namecheap or godaddy or ....
Then you like the EXTERNAL ip address to the new purchased domain. You don't use your personal DNS to map your machines public internet facing ip to a domain, thats what someone like google DNS or opendns does.

Webmin will use a port number by default it is 10000. That means that webmin is looking for a connection to the server it is installed on at port 10000.

The kind of DNS server you referenced are more for internal networks behind NAT.

ANSWER: go to http://'your_ip>':10000

Go to namecheap.com, buy a domain. In the dns section put in the ip address of that server. That will "link" the domain to the ip.

Comment: I meant what that it links the domain to the IP but I explained in a bad way. I'm just confused about one thing. in the BIND configuration tutorial it shows that they use a domain to set the DNS server on and the nameservers before for example ns1.example.com ns2.example.com. How did they link that Domain to the server without a DNS server in the first place? I already got my domain I just can't link it without DNS server and can't set DNS server without domain. I'm confused.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Can you edit the original with a clearer question or more detail?

Comment: I edited the whole question, I found it not explaining much. Is it better now?

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't answer my question yet.

Comment: Alright, forget what I said. All I have now is a server, IP and webmin control panel. How can I link my domain to my server? from scratch.

Comment: That means that I can use the IP of my server directly without using a DNS? just by putting in the IP adress and the domain will directly forward to the IP?

Comment: Think of an ip address as a phone number and a domain as the contract in your phone book. If you know the number (ip) just put it in the browser and hit enter.

Comment: Okay, and now when I register a domain do I have to have DNS server? Or I can just link the domain directly to my IP?

Comment: The company you pay for the domain will have a dns server. They will make the entry for you.

Comment: Ah, great, so when I host my domain at namecheap all I have to do is to give them the IP of my server and they'll point the IP to their DNS server and everything, right? Just answer that and you really saved my day :D

Comment: That's all, their support should help you out if you have questions

Comment: I suggest you move the final answer from the comment section to the actual answer text. As it is now, the answer isn't there.